# I'm new to python and my coding class is starting with "Tracy" turtle graphics, my code isn't working

Tags: python

Don't worry about the functions, they are perfectly functional. I'm having trouble with this while
loop as whenever I run the code it continuously repeats the check_mark(), up_arrow(), and down_arrow()
functions. I know its something wrong with my while loop, and I need to use an if/elif/else statement,   I'm just not sure how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
speed(0)
secret_number = 7
user_number = int(input("Guess the secret number(1-10): "))
while secret_number == 7:
        if secret_number > user_number:
                down_arrow()
        elif secret_number < user_number:
                up_arrow()
        else:
                check_mark()
```

Comment: You never change the value of `secret_number` inside the loop, unless the functions you didn't share change it.

Comment: I can share the functions if you think that they would help the overall situation

Comment: You probably want `while secret_number != user_number:`, input a new user number inside the loop, and call `check_mark` after the loop exits (which `user_number` *does* equal `secret_number`.

Comment: what does "isnt' working" mean? what does it do?

Comment: The fact that it repeats `check_mark(), up_arrow(), and down_arrow()` suggests that these functions change `user_number` or `secret_number`, so please add them to the description.

Comment: If you can replicate the problem without calling them, leave them out of the question entirely. E.g., `if secret_number > user_number: pass elif ...`

Comment: Well, when I say doesn't work, I mean this: The user inputs a number and it does the corresponding function based on if the input() is bigger, smaller, or equal to the secret_number. However, when that function runs it repeats the function over and over again making multiple shapes of the same function I also need the while loop to make it so that if the user guesses the number wrong they can guess again. But when I go to guess again it doesn't allow me to. idk I'm stupid at coding.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow :) I'd recommend reading some of our new user materials if you're here to stick around! Specifically, we discourage "Unhelpful" titles - most people who come here have code that isn't working. A title should provide a concise summary of your problem. Also, we expect a question to explain both what you expect to happen and what actually happens, along with any relevant code, even if it seems obvious. Don't copy your entire program here, but do try to make sure we have enough info to solve your problem :)

Comment: def check_mark():
    color("green")
    pensize(15)
    penup()
    setposition(-100,0)
    pendown()
    right(45)
    forward(100)
    left(90)
    forward(200)
def up_arrow():
    pensize(15)
    color("yellow")
    left(90)
    backward(100)
    forward(200)
    right(45)
    backward(25)
    forward(25)
    right(90)
    forward(25)
def down_arrow():
    pensize(15)
    color("yellow")
    right(90)
    backward(100)
    forward(200)
    left(135)
    forward(25)
    backward(25)
    left(90)
    forward(25)         Here are the functions

Comment: @IcoSli please post any information relevant to the question as an edit to the question - the comments here are not necessarily permanent.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do here, I think you meant something like this:

```py
speed(0)
secret_number = 7
while True:
        user_number = int(input("Guess the secret number(1-10): "))
        if secret_number > user_number:
                down_arrow()
        elif secret_number < user_number:
                up_arrow()
        else:
                check_mark()
                break
```

I made three changes:

1. Changed `secret_number == 7` to `True` in the `while` loop condition. It does the same thing because `secret_number` is always equal to 7, but it's easier to understand this way.
2. The `while` loop never ends because the condition is always `True`. I think you'd want to exit the loop when the user guesses the number. So I added a `break` in the final `else` branch.
3. Moved the input of `user_number` into the `while` loop so that the question is asked again and again as long as the answer is wrong, instead of only once.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but rather than `while True`, I think OP is looking for `while secret_number != user_number`, though OP has said nothing to explain this, it seems like the most logical goal of this snippet. EDIT: I've just noticed your break statement. I'm guessing they may not have covered break yet, and may be trying to encourage use of conditional while loops. That said, your code would work the same way as the version I suggest. (though personally I would never recommend a `while True` loop... it's bad practice IMO)

Comment: @bendl Also possible, if you remember to initialize `user_number` outside the loop (e.g. to `None`). And you'd essentially be duplicating the equality check, which seems a bit redundant. A matter of preference.

Comment: I just posted an edit - I did not see that break statement in my first glance

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I ran it, did a little tweak to change the positioning, and now it works, I used the secre_number != user_number that bendl suggested as well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

While functions will keep iterating, as long as the statement is true. In your code, the secret number is set at 7, so the statement in the while loop is true. However, because the secret number remains 7, the while loop will keep repeating infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

`secret_number` is 7, and never changes in the code you've provided.

Your while loop continues executing for as long as `secret_number == 7`

Therefore it will execute forever.  It keeps asking "is the secret number 7?" and the answer is always "yes"